# libGDX remember ScrollPane last Y position after create

Tags: libgdx

I'm using `Libgdx` and `scrollpane` widget for my levels screen.

I want to remember last Y position of `scrollpane`, and to set this Y position on next open on levels screen.

```
lastScrollPositionY = scrollPane.getScrollY();
```

after creating scrollpane elements I call:

@Override

```
public void show() {
    createScrollPane();
    ...        
    scrollPane.setScrollY(lastScrollPositionY);
    ...        
}
```

but scroll doesn't move to saved positon.

If I call  `setScrollY` on button click this code work well, but immediately after creating this not working. 
I want to move scroll immediately  after creating component, I don't want delay.

Please give me some advice?

Thanks

Comment: Cheap fix might be to do this:
scrollPane.addAction(Actions.delayedAction(.1f,Actions.runnable(scrollPane.setScrollY(lastScrollPositionY);))

That's not the exact syntax but hopefully you get the idea

Comment: tnx for advice, but I have visible delay. First scroll is on top and then immediately go on saved position. i want to do this, without visible dely

Comment: what is in you createScrollPane()?

Comment: Maybe you can do it in the first call to your screen's render() and it will get rid of any delay? You'd just have to keep track and only do it once.

Comment: @Barodapride  thanks for your last comment, this solve my issue. Maybe this isn't clean solution, but  work. Post this as answer I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: Maybe setScrollY needs to be done after you add the scrollPane to the stage. That could be done in show(). That would make things simpler.